# Universal: some routes are working and some are not working

Tags: angular

[Link](https://github.com/goodmite/universal-not-working/blob/master/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts) to the repo in the question

**Summary:**

I forked [angular-universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repo and added one route. But surprisingly, its just not working. I can't seem to understand why it's not working. The routes that were originally in the repo are working fine.

I created prerendered SSR using this commend as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter):

```
npm run build:prerender && npm run serve:prerender
```

**Details question:**

The repo originally had `/lazy` route. Which works fine in all the following cases:

1. In normal app (served by ng serve)
2. In SSR app, when first navigated to `/` and then clicked a button to navigate to `/lazy`
3. In SSR app, when directly navigated to `/lazy`
4. In SSR app (Javascript disabled in browser), when directly navigated to `/lazy`

I added a routes `/login`, which:

1. In normal app (served by ng serve) : **Works fine**
2. In SSR app, when first navigated to / and then clicked a button to navigate to `/login`: **Works fine**
3. In SSR app, when directly navigated to `/login` : **Doesnt work**
4. In SSR app (Javascript disabled in browser), when directly navigated to `/login`: **Doesnt work**. I get following error:

> (No webpage was found for the web address:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8080/login)

---

Routes are as follows:

**app.module.ts ([link](https://github.com/goodmite/universal-not-working/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts))**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'login', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'},
    ]),
```

**lazy.module.ts ([link](https://github.com/goodmite/universal-not-working/blob/master/src/app/lazy/lazy.module.ts))**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: LazyComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
    ])
```

---

**Edit:**

**server.ts ([link](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts))** is configured to alway send index.html

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

Comment: Check this out https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: It is already configured to send index.html. Otherwise reloading `/lazy` wont work as well. See my edit. Thanks